# Why doesn't this work? ''.join(' '.join(string).split().remove(str[n]))

Tags: python, string, join, behavior

I'm playing with `codingbat.com,` and I found this really easy problem to solve, so I started trying to play newbie code golf.

> Given a non-empty string and an int n, return a new string where the
>   char at index n has been removed. The value of n will be a valid index
>   of a char in the original string (i.e. n will be in the range
>   0..len(str)-1 inclusive).
>
> missing_char('kitten', 1) → 'ktten'
>  missing_char('kitten', 0) →
>   'itten'
>  missing_char('kitten', 4) → 'kittn'

Das Code:

```
def missing_char(str, n):
  return ''.join(' '.join(str).split().remove(str[n]))
```

Oddly, Python won't interpret this. 
Why not?

Comment: Could you be more precise about what goes wrong/what error you get?

Comment: `str` is a bad name for an identifier, since it hides the [`built-in str`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=str#str)

Comment: Also note that, `.remove()` removes the first matching item from a list. Your code would fail for, say, `strng='killing'` and `n=4`. Also you could make a list from a string easily with `list(strng)`.

Comment: `str` is a bad name for golf, since it is more than one character

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is because `remove` returns `None`.  Most (all?) builtin functions in python that mutate a value return `None`.

Therefore your outer `join` is trying to join nothing together.

Answer (score 9):

Not a direct answer to your question, but that seems like a very hard way to do a slice...

```
def missing_char(s, n):
    return s[:n] + s[n+1:]
```

Answer (score 2):

Golfed version

```
missing_char=lambda s,n:s[:n]+s[n+1:]
```

Comment: @Shon, if you like code golf, you should check out http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I'll definitely check it out.